# What is the most amount of edges a directed graph can have without having a cycle?

Tags: graph

Working on a graph, and this information would be useful, but it is hard to calculate. Thanks!

Attempted solution: Run a BFS and for each subsequent layer add an edge from all vertices of one BFS layer to all vertices of the next BFS layer.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt would give the maximum number of edges.  Another way to look at it is to number the vertices `1` through `n`, and have an edge connecting each vertex to all higher numbered vertices, for a total of `n(n-1)/2` edges.

To see that you can’t have any more edges, you just have to realize that once you have more than `n(n-1)/2` edges, there must be some pair of vertices connected to each other in each direction, forming a cycle.